# Android app giving multidex run time error duplicate entry: (Can't read (Duplicate zip entry ))

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting the following error while running an app. I am unable to identified why I am facing this issue.

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>
> > java.io.IOException: Can't write [GooglePlaces\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar]
> >     (Can't read [C:\Program Files\Android\Android
> >     Studio\gradle\m2repository\com\google\code\findbugs\jsr305\1.3.9\jsr305-1.3.9.jar(;;;;;;**.class)]
> >     (Duplicate zip entry
> >     [jsr305-1.3.9.jar:javax/annotation/CheckForNull.class]))

Here is my code of gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    useLibrary  'org.apache.http.legacy'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId ""
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:11.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.2.0'
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android2-1.10.3-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.10.1-beta.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-asl-1.9.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
}
```

help me if you can, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the [guava library](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/google/guava/guava/11.0.1/guava-11.0.1.pom) has the same dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
   <version>1.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

Remove this line:

```
compile files('libs/jsr305-1.3.9.jar')
```